# POST header with token bearer

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I am trying to `POST` authorization token in header using `OkHttp`. I am trying something like this, but unfortunately, i've got **`415 error`** in debug mode. Thanks in advance.

```
private void Logout() throws IOException{
    String postBody = "test post";
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient= new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown"), postBody);
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("ABC")
            .addHeader("Authorization",tokenBearer)
            .post(body)
            .build();

    okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(okhttp3.Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(okhttp3.Call call, okhttp3.Response response) throws IOException {

            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                String message= response.body().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: 415 is unsupported media type i think this : `RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(
            MediaType.parse("text/x-markdown"), postBody);` has problem.

Comment: I suggest you add a logging interceptor and add the output of the logcat on the question. I am not sure that is a problem of token because 415 is Unsupported Media Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**415** code stands for **unsupported media type**.
Here is what you can do in this case:

1. If you have such a possibility, consider using `application/json` or something like that. Usually APIs have such option.
2. `text/x-markdown` is not used widely, try to replace it with `text/markdown`.
3. If nothing works for you, try getting `text/plain` and create a small parcer that will process markdown